# Connect to Google Search Console API from a Google Colab Notebook using OAuth

Tags: oauth, google-colaboratory, google-search-console

i'm trying to connect to Google Search Console API from a Google Colab Notebook using OAuth but the authorisation fails with an Error 400: invalid_request (see screenshot [oauth error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivAof.png))

i have been following google's official documentation using the code:

- https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v1/quickstart/quickstart-python#step_4_set_up_the_sample

```
import httplib2

from apiclient import errors
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow


# Copy your credentials from the console
CLIENT_ID = '___'
CLIENT_SECRET = '___'

# Check https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v1/ for all available scopes
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly'

# Redirect URI for installed apps
REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'

# Run through the OAuth flow and retrieve credentials
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI)
authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
print ('Go to the following link in your browser: ' + authorize_url)
code = input('Enter verification code: ').strip()
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
```

but also a tutorial which specifically sets up the connection through a colab notebook

- https://www.oncrawl.com/technical-seo/extract-data-google-search-console-data-analysis-in-python/
- using https://github.com/joshcarty/google-searchconsole

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/joshcarty/google-searchconsole

import searchconsole
account = searchconsole.authenticate(client_config='client_secret_.json',serialize='credentials.json', flow='console')
```

known differences in workflow/setup:

- oauth application type is 'Desktop App' because 'Other' is not available to choose
- also been using application type 'Web Application' with the result Error '400: redirect_uri_mismatch'

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the official documentation is outdated.

According to [Google Developer's blog](https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/02/making-oauth-flows-safer.html#instructions-oob), OAuth out-of-band (oob) is getting deprecated:

> Feb 28, 2022 - new OAuth usage will be blocked for the OOB flow

In other words, the feature of manually copying an auth token from the browser, and pasting it to the application, should not be used anymore because of security reasons.

On this link there is also a suggestion on how to specifically solve it for different clients (iOS, Android, Chrome, and Desktop applications). I had this problem with JavaScript and I solved it by creating an HTTP server that listens to an arbitrary port on the localhost, which is automatically triggered by the OAuth2 authentication flow with the generated token.

You need to change *redirect_uri* to make it point to this port. For example: in case your server listens to port 3000, *redirect_uri* could be **http://localhost:3000/** instead of **urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob**.